# How to append a `<div>` before/after selected `<p>` element by given clientHeight?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a problem to add a `div` before `paragraph` element by given `clientHeight`. In this case, I want to get nearest `paragraph` from given `clientHeight` and add a `div` after/before that element.

Here the example:

```
<div id="content">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  <p>Paragraph 5</p>
</div>
```

I want to get the nearest `<p>` from `30px` clientHeight, then add a `div`.

How i can do that?

Comment: The things is i just want to get the nearest `p` from given height in pixel, and add a `div`

Answer (score 1):

Get all your Ps, and find the closest

```
let myPs = document.querySelectorAll("P");
if (myPs.length == 0) //handle this error case
else {
  var bestP, bestDist;
  bestP = myPs[0];
  bestDist = ... // calculate the minimum distance from either y or y + height to `clientHeight` for myPs[0]
  for (let i = 1; i < myPs.length; i++) {
    // compare distance as about to bestDist. If less, replace bestDist and bestP
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the offsetTop of the children to offsetTop of parent

```js
const addDividers = (el) => {
  ['beforebegin', 'afterend'].forEach(pos => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = 'DIVIDER';
    el.insertAdjacentElement(pos, div);
  });
}

const cont = document.getElementById('content'),
  wanted = Array.from(cont.children).find(el => el.offsetTop >= cont.offsetTop+ 30 );

if (wanted) {
  addDividers(wanted)
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  <p>Paragraph 5</p>
</div>
```